# How to use spaces in "if"?

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to see if a string is the same as another string by using if, but the string contains spaces!

It looks something like this:

```
if %DriveDir%==NOT BOOT FILES echo Working
```

Simply put, it says "BOOT was unexpected at this time"

```
if %DriveDir%=="NOT BOOT FILES" echo Working
if %DriveDir%==%nbf% echo Working
```

I have tried using quotes and storing the string in a variable like this, but nothing changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should also add quotes to variables.

```
if "%DriveDir%"=="NOT BOOT FILES" echo Working
```

Comment: oh my god i completely forgot about that

Answer (score 0):

batch file interpretation is very literal. you are not really using variables, they all get replaced with their values on load. so the line

```
if %DriveDir%=="NOT BOOT FILES" echo Working
```

gets expanded to

```
if NOT BOOT FILES=="NOT BOOT FILES" echo Working
```

which is obviously syntactically incorrect. you need to have the same expression on both sides, and the `NOT` gets parsed as `IF NOT…` , so you need to surround both wih quotes.