# Making spaces irrelevant in a .bat file

Tags: batch-file

I am running into a bit of a problem in my batch script. I know that /I makes the IF statement not cap sensitive but is the something similar to making it not space sensitive?

Comment: Just to make sure that this is not an ["XY Problem"](http://xyproblem.info/), could you please tell us what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: Putting quotes around expressions containing spaces might help...

Comment: I have the if statement set up like this: "IF /I '%talk%' == 'Howareyou' GOTO HOWAREYOU"   I want to make it to where it can recognize it if you type "How are you"... How would I do that?

Comment: Adding quotation marks did not work.

Comment: I see, okay, you are right, you do really need to ignore spaces. I do not want to even think how horrible this is going to be to implement in a batch file.  Sorry, can't help.  If I had to do something like this I would use a high level language.

Comment: It is to make it easy so people can go in and tack on there own stuff really easily.

Comment: 1. put your sample code into the question by editing the post; 2. replace the single-quotes `'` double-quotes `"`, then it will work as expected, even with spaces;

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use spaces in "if"?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25598573/5047996).

Comment: For future reference, `"` is a quote, `'` is an apostrophe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to remove the spaces. Just put double-quotes around both expressions to compare:

```
if /I "%talk%"=="How are you" goto HOWAREYOU
```

The double-quotes also avoid trouble with other characters special to command prompt (like <kbd>SPACE</kbd>, <kbd>TAB</kbd>, `,`, `;`, `=`, `^`, `&`, `(`, `)`, `<`, `>`, `|`).

Answer (score 1):

After you have your `talk` variable defined, you can use string substitution to remove the spaces. Like following:

```
set "_temp=%talk: =%"
```

Then you use the `%_temp%` variable to make your `IF` comparison.

Hint: The double quotes around the full `set` command is just to make your variable declaration more precise, avoiding unwanted following spaces.

Source:
http://www.dostips.com/DtTipsStringManipulation.php

Comment: I would still suggest you to edit the question to make it more clear about what you are asking about. Many misunderstandings at the comments... And "Accept" the answer if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `findstr` with [conditional execution](http://www.dostips.com/?t=Snippets.ConditionalExecution) to perform a regular expression match.

```js
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
echo(!talk! | findstr /i "how *are *you" && (
    rem Match.
) || (
    rem No match.
)
```

Delayed expansion prevents premature evaluation of the contents of the variable (user entered an ampersand or whatever).  Using `echo(` with the parenthesis prevents evaluation of user entry of `/?`.