# How to use spaces in user-input variables for "If" and "If not" statements in Batch?

Tags: batch-file, if-statement, user-input

I am making a Batch script that uses user-input variables with "If" and "If not" statements. Simple? Yes. However, the "If" and "If not" statements require a space in the user-input variable, and if you type in the user-input variable with a space, that causes many problems.

Keep in mind I am fairly new to coding, but here's my script.

```
@echo off
:B
echo Enter password:
set /p password=
if %password% == Password WithASpace goto :A
if not %password% == Password WithASpace goto :C
:C
echo Incorrect password
cls
goto :B
:A
echo Correct password, unlocking secret FBI database.
pause
```

I tried putting quotation marks around the "Password WithASpace" text in the If and If Not statements. That didn't work either. The command-prompt just says "Password WithASpace" was unexpected at this time and it closes immediately.

```
@echo off
:B
echo Enter password:
set /p password=
if %password% == Password WithASpace goto :A
if not %password% == Password WithASpace goto :C
:C
echo Incorrect password
cls
goto :B
:A
echo Correct password, unlocking secret FBI database.
pause
```

So how do I fix this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use spaces in "if"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25598573/how-to-use-spaces-in-if)

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why quotes didn't work for you.
This works for me:

```
@echo off
:B
echo Enter password:
set /p password=
if "%password%" == "Password WithASpace" goto :A
if not "%password%" == "Password WithASpace" goto :C
:C
echo Incorrect password
cls
goto :B
:A
echo Correct password, unlocking secret FBI database.
pause
```

Comment: I think it is because I forgot to add quotation marks around %password.% Thanks!