# i want to set the output of a command to a variable and compare it with another variable batch

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have an issue here: I want to set a variable to the output of a command and use that variable in an `if` statement but I get an error.

Below is a code snippet of what I have tried; it gets the variable but the comparison of the `if` statement does not work:

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions 
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ( 
'ver' 
) do ( 
set myvar=%%a 
) 
echo %myvar% 
pause 

if %myvar%==1 (
echo yes
) else (
echo no
)
pause
endlocal
```

Comment: What's the error? What actually do you want to do? What's your expecting behavior?

Comment: The output string of `ver` contains spaces, which cause trouble in the `if` statement...

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How to use spaces in "if"?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25598573)

Comment: Comment out or remove the `@echo off` to see what the script is really doing. `@echo off` considered harmful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `if %myvar%==1 (` to `if "%myvar%"=="1" (`.